# XML Signature element is not declared

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I created XSD using Visual StudioXML Tools. And I use following C# code to validate XML and facing this error.

**Error**

> The element is not declared
>   'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature'.

**So my question is how to fix it because in edit mode XML is valid 100%?**

Thank you!

**C#**

```
  private void buttonValidateXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {            
                bool result = IsValidXml2(textBoxSignedXML.Text, textBoxXSDFile.Text, "");
                rtbValidationResult.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rtbValidationResult.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

public static bool IsValidXml2(string xmlFilePath, string xsdFilePath, string namespaceName)
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemas.Add(namespaceName, xsdFilePath);

            bool result = true;
            xdoc.Validate(schemas, (sender, e) =>
            {
                result = false;
            });

            return result;
        }
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope version="1">
  <Deposit>
    <ClientId>1234567890123</ClientId>
    <Account>0045678</Account>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Total>5000.00</Total>
    <SignedDate>2016-02-15</SignedDate>     
    <Cheques>
      <Cheque>
        <Images>
          <Front>
            SUkqAAgAAAAPAP4ABAABAAAAAAAAAAABBAABAAAAfQUAAAEBBAABAAAAWgIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQAA
            AAMBAwABAAAABAAAAAYBAwABAAAAAAAAAA4BAgAhAAAA0AAAABEBBAABAAAAAAIAABIBAwABAAAA
            AQAAABUBAwABAAAAAQAAABYBBAABAAAAWgIAABcBBAABAAAAvi8AABoBBQABAAAAAAEAABsBBQAB
            EdF0fRG0R0YRdH2R2XzaI6OxRQAQAQA=
          </Front>
          <Back>
            SUkqAAgAAAAOAP4ABAABAAAAAAAAAAABBAABAAAAgQUAAAEBBAABAAAAVAIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQAA
            AAMBAwABAAAABAAAAAYBAwABAAAAAAAAABEBBAABAAAAAAEAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABUBAwABAAAA
            AQAAABYBBAABAAAAVAIAABcBBAABAAAAcggAABoBBQABAAAAwAAAABsBBQABAAAA0AAAACgBAwAB
            AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMgAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//LZCdO1f7iRrKXTqt//pePx///9lNoL487Ajh
            jFyzUrtwg+6gg9VmvCIWA42XMwziSUEEw7GoIcSUWZ3Y0oKmGR3LToGVC2LhkK6H4sorQNRUMLjH
            LTGzlpv3RFCcH4NLB9hvLTmD8tMgOsG+WVaR5AweTcEWMMfaDQxDIx5NwVQx8OMPeGFHLSUlLcSS
            1JtNV/9/rrffuO+h9bx////kfvABABAA
          </Back>
        </Images>
        <MicrCodeCmc>123456789012345678901234567890</MicrCodeCmc>
        <Amount>465.22</Amount>
        <PaymentDate>2016-02-15</PaymentDate>
        <EmissionDate>2016-02-15</EmissionDate>
      </Cheque>
      <Cheque>
        <Images>
          <Front>
            SUkqAAgAAAAPAP4ABAABAAAAAAAAAAABBAABAAAAfQUAAAEBBAABAAAAWgIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQAA
            AAMBAwABAAAABAAAAAYBAwABAAAAAAAAAA4BAgAhAAAA0AAAABEBBAABAAAAAAIAABIBAwABAAAA
            AQAAABUBAwABAAAAAQAAABYBBAABAAAAWgIAABcBBAABAAAAvi8AABoBBQABAAAAAAEAABsBBQAB
            EdF0fRG0R0YRdH2R2XzaI6OxRQAQAQA=
          </Front>
          <Back>
            SUkqAAgAAAAOAP4ABAABAAAAAAAAAAABBAABAAAAgQUAAAEBBAABAAAAVAIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQAA
            AAMBAwABAAAABAAAAAYBAwABAAAAAAAAABEBBAABAAAAAAEAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABUBAwABAAAA
            AQAAABYBBAABAAAAVAIAABcBBAABAAAAcggAABoBBQABAAAAwAAAABsBBQABAAAA0AAAACgBAwAB
            AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMgAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//LZCdO1f7iRrKXTqt//pePx///9lNoL487Ajh
            jFyzUrtwg+6gg9VmvCIWA42XMwziSUEEw7GoIcSUWZ3Y0oKmGR3LToGVC2LhkK6H4sorQNRUMLjH
            LTGzlpv3RFCcH4NLB9hvLTmD8tMgOsG+WVaR5AweTcEWMMfaDQxDIx5NwVQx8OMPeGFHLSUlLcSS
            1JtNV/9/rrffuO+h9bx////kfvABABAA
          </Back>
        </Images>
        <MicrCodeCmc>123456789012345678901234567890</MicrCodeCmc>
        <Amount>99999999999</Amount>
        <PaymentDate>2016-02-15</PaymentDate>
        <EmissionDate>2016-02-15</EmissionDate>
      </Cheque>
    </Cheques>
  </Deposit>   
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>TVO2Gssf5TUdXFYG/PrHDyqYFqs=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>KwQInN03ywa0u0t4HedxgE1fOU7XYLQScKuQ6vdYoIZME5Hm5jpFeX2ORA2U+BO7JNjmFilTW05VntS3k98YCZhNXH9Iw/YEC1nw4JJLzygYbbCftkiY5v5+b494mQPryCtscwTtbziW6QilILSFDGmco2JopRfVe+qfdN/JyB1HXhUfApyNEsw/cJLj6aaz5ivN1sLFgAlikbwCNpF+mRnZY5u7/S8uT8WhEyK32EcatdjzKbP0PwnIlumhOpUMerWeLZ7neuJq6R/IuFgZ1Y5U6ppyuOjhtiHp4glC/uNUS/y7jMzG29thWBkEtSE9AcEt2IZ0HOEZE3kdFXufjA==</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</Envelope>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://example.com/ct-required"
           xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" >

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
            schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"/>

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="PNGPictureType"
          xmime:expectedContentTypes="image/png">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="Money">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:totalDigits value="13" />
      <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
      <xs:minInclusive value="0.00" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="99999999999.99" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="Currency">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Currency Code: ISO 4217</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="USD" />
            <xs:enumeration value="UYU" />
            <xs:minLength value="3" />
            <xs:maxLength value="3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="Envelope">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Deposit" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ClientId" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
              <xs:element name="Account" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
              <xs:element name="Currency" type="Currency" />
              <xs:element name="Total" type="Money" />
              <xs:element name="SignedDate" type="xs:date" />
              <xs:element name="Cheques">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Cheque">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Images">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Front" type="PNGPictureType" />
                                <xs:element name="Back" type="PNGPictureType" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="MicrCodeCmc" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Amount" type="Money" />
                          <xs:element name="PaymentDate" type="xs:date" />
                          <xs:element name="EmissionDate" type="xs:date" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" ref="q1:Signature" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**UPDATE #1**

I have tried different approaches but no joy.

[image]

And even if I reference XSD to local file it does not work. I see the same error.

```
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212 file:///C:/Temp/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

UPDATE #2

Even I use this approach no joy.

```
 public static bool IsValidXml1(string xmlFilePath, string xsdFilePath, string namespaceName)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = null;
            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

            try
            {
                using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings))
                {
                    xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr);
                    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
                    schemas.Add(namespaceName, xsdFilePath);
                    schemas.Add(@"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", @"D:\Temp\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd");
                    xdoc.Validate(schemas, null);

                    return true;
                }                
            }
            catch (XmlSchemaValidationException ex)
            {
                // throw;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well... I have to use XSD file to validate XML...

Comment: @dimi - you are applying the XmlReader fix to the wrong input file.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:  If you provide another mechanism to resolve the namespace beyond what a complete `xs:import` would do, then you can succeed in correcting the problem without changing the XSD.  However, the most interoperable fix would be to complete the `xs:import` [**as I've shown**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42440995/290085); then, OP and other parties will be able to validate with just the XML and XSD, without an additional mechanism to bind the imported XSD to the namespace.  If you could add a specific `XmlReader` fix to the XSD fix, the total problem may be resolved.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you might be interested in my solution since it avoids your kludge with modification of dsig xsd.

Comment: I already figured that out - and pointed the OP to how to fix it. You don't need the outer XmlReader, just the second one.

Comment: @HenkHolterman well I think I read all comments and did not find it anywhere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to change anything to xsd or xml - do the following:

1. (optional) Download xsd from [w3 site](http://view-source:https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd) and save to local disk. W3 site is VERY slow because a lot of software worldwide constantly request those schemas. If you will use that xsd directly - you will often fail by timeout. Some validation tools already have such schemas cached locally, but not .NET validator.
2. Modify your validation method from UPDATE 2 the following way:

   ```
   public static bool IsValidXml1(string xmlFilePath, string xsdFilePath, string namespaceName)
   {
       XDocument xdoc = null;
       var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
       settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

       try
       {
           using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings))
           {
               xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr);
               var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();                    
               schemas.Add(namespaceName, xsdFilePath);                   
               using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\Temp\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd")) 
               using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs, new XmlReaderSettings() {
                   DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore // important
               })) {
                   schemas.Add(@"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", reader);
               }

               xdoc.Validate(schemas, null);

               return true;
           }
       }
       catch (XmlSchemaValidationException ex)
       {
           // throw;
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```

You have to add that schema using `XmlReader` and not directly, because if you add directly (like in your update 2) - it will fail to parse DTD block, because when you add `XmlSchema` to `XmlSchemaSet` using url (or file path) - it will read that file using `XmlReaderSettings` with `DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit`. We need to change that to `DtdProcessing.Ignore` or `DtdProcessing.Parse`. After that your validation method will work fine for target xsd and xml file, without any changes (and will correctly fail in case xml does not match xsd).

Comment: It works from the first attempt! Thanks, bro! God bless you!

Answer (score 10):

You are very close.  In your XSD, simply replace,

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
```

with

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
           schemaLocation=
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

and your XSD will no longer have that error, and your XML will be valid against your XSD.

### Explanation

XSDs can be composed via [`xs:import` and `xs:include`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357943/whats-the-difference-between-xsdinclude-and-xsdimport).  In both cases, the location of the referenced XSD has to be specified with a required `schemaLocation` attribute, which was missing in OP's original XSD.  By adding `xs:import/@schemaLocation` as shown above, the error is eliminated.

---

### Update #1:

When you switched to use a local XSD, you made a mistake in your `xs:import`:

Change

```
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
            schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212 
                            file:///C:/Temp/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

to

```
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
            schemaLocation="file:///C:/Temp/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

(You were following an example for `@xsi:schemaLocation` in XML documents which has namespace-location *pairs*; `xs:import/@schemaLocation` is different.)

---

### Update #2:

> **So my question is how to fix it because in edit mode XML is valid 100%?**

Perhaps this is the disconnect.  Editing an XML file in Visual Studio does not automatically validate it against an XSD. You need to do that in code or via a validating XML editor such [Oxygen XML Editor](https://www.oxygenxml.com/) or [XML Spy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html).

Also, your C# validation code may have issues.  See [Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you explain? I've never had to do this.

Comment: I am sorry but it does not work. It says:  
Warning  Imported schema for namespace  http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# was not resolved

Comment: @Dimi: The above correction is necessary to eliminate the error in your XSD, and once made, your XML is valid according to your corrected XSD.   I have confirmed this independent of your code.  I suggest that you validate your XML with an independent XML editor against your XSD to be sure that you've not made a mistake updating your XSD.

Comment: Please take a look at my question I just added a new screenshot with this warning.

Comment: Enter `http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` into your browser and make sure that you have connectivity to the schema location.  If it does not come up, or if it takes excessively long and is causing time-outs, then that is the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... It opens really fast under a browser. Would you mind to suggest a syntax to reference to local xmldsig-core-schema.xsd file please? Should it be like <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>

Comment: See [**How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253402/how-to-reference-a-local-xml-schema-file-correctly)

Comment: Hey... I just tried the local file and it does not work. Please see my updated question. Would you mind to help me please?

Comment: With all due respect  to your answer and comments, would you mind to help me to resolve this issue? I have tried ALL OPTIONS  but nothing is working.

Comment: Answer updated.  Last tip: Strongly suggest that you first get your XML and XSD correct as I've shown, *then* worry about your C# code.  **I have shown you exactly what you need to do to fix your XSD so your XML will validate.**  I need to move on -- you've asked a whole series of follow-ups, and this site is not intended for ongoing exchanges.  Use separate questions for any future issues.  Thanks, and good luck.

Comment: Answer updated.  My approach *does* resolve the error you report ("The element is not declared...") but you may have additional problems with your C# code.  See **[Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp)** for how to validate XML against an XSD in C#.

Comment: Hi. You know the idea of XSD is validate XML. That is why I ineed a full answer. I need implement correct validation for XML and XSD I have got. If you are able to help me then you will gain 500. Thank you!